# How to remove duplicates when concatenating array to string field in a PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, list

I am trying to concatenate a list of languages applied to each feature_id. However there is a lot of duplication. Do anyone know why this occurs and how to only allow one type of each language?

```
--indivdual features diff with list of all languages applied
SELECT 
  t1.feature_id,
  array_to_string(array_agg(t2.language), ', ') AS applied_languages_in_old_version,
  array_to_string(array_agg(t4.language), ', ') AS applied_languages_in_new_verison
FROM kh_bel_territory_2023mar14.kh_bel_territory_2023mar14_territory t1
INNER JOIN kh_bel_territory_2023mar14.kh_bel_territory_2023mar14_territory_name t2
ON t1.feature_id = t2.feature_id
INNER JOIN kh_bel_territories_08nov2022.kh_bel_territories_08nov2022_territory t3
ON t2.feature_id = t3.feature_id
INNER JOIN kh_bel_territories_08nov2022.kh_bel_territories_08nov2022_territory_name t4
ON t3.feature_id = t4.feature_id
WHERE t2.name_type = 'PRIMARY_FOR_LANGUAGE' 
AND t4.name_type = 'PRIMARY_FOR_LANGUAGE'
GROUP BY 
  t1.feature_id
ORDER BY t1.feature_id;
```

[image]

Comment: Note that `array_to_string(array_agg(t2.language), ', ')` can be simplified to `string_agg(t2.language, ', ')`

Answer (score 1):

`DISTINCT` may be helpful here. It can go into the `ARRAY_AGG` to aggregate a distinct list of elements.

```
SELECT 
  t1.feature_id,
  array_to_string(array_agg(DISTINCT t2.language), ', ') AS applied_languages_in_old_version,
  array_to_string(array_agg(DISTINCT t4.language), ', ') AS applied_languages_in_new_verison
FROM kh_bel_territory_2023mar14.kh_bel_territory_2023mar14_territory t1
INNER JOIN kh_bel_territory_2023mar14.kh_bel_territory_2023mar14_territory_name t2
ON t1.feature_id = t2.feature_id
INNER JOIN kh_bel_territories_08nov2022.kh_bel_territories_08nov2022_territory t3
ON t2.feature_id = t3.feature_id
INNER JOIN kh_bel_territories_08nov2022.kh_bel_territories_08nov2022_territory_name t4
ON t3.feature_id = t4.feature_id
WHERE t2.name_type = 'PRIMARY_FOR_LANGUAGE' 
AND t4.name_type = 'PRIMARY_FOR_LANGUAGE'
GROUP BY 
  t1.feature_id
ORDER BY t1.feature_id;
```